# iphone imageview orientation going wrong for portraitUpsideDown

Tags: iphone, orientation

I have a UIViewController which displays image along with some description. This page does not support any other orientation except portrait. On this page, when user click on image, I display image in full screen view using a UIImageViewController. This page supports all the orientation. When I am in landscape mode on second page and go back to the detail page then detail page automatically rotate back to portrait mode. but if I am in portraitUpsideDown on second page and then go back to detail page then this also keep displaying in portraitUpsideDown. How can I force the details page to display in portrait mode and not in portraitUpsideDown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your detail page has

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

and not

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

on orientation method.

else you need to paste some code of orientation you using for both the classes so that one will know where you're doing any mistake.

Comment: That is correct. Also if it was the reason then it will always be UpsideDown. But basically it rotates back to portrait if the second page was in landscape. Otherwise it remain whatever portrait mode it was whether Up or down.